# calculating probability of an event

Tags: probability

I have encountered a question

> The weather report says that there is a P probability of rainfalls
>   today. Raj has to step out for a meeting at the office, and would like
>   to know the probability that it rains during the time he is on the
>   way. T is the time is the (in minutes), it will take for Raj to reach his office.

Now , i have the following questions for this.

1.Why can't the probability be calculated as P*T. It can be thought of as sum of probability values of each minute.  Also why cant it be `1-pow(1-P,T)`?

2.In the answer for this problem, the formula given is

```
1-pow(1-P,T/1440.0))
```

What kind of probability calculation is this? What does the factor T/1440 signifies here?

Answer (score 1):

The factor $T\over 1440$ signifies time $T$ minutes out of a total of $1440$ minutes in a day.

Hence, the answer is $1-$Pr("It won't rain in the *T* minutes") = $'1-pow(1-P,T/1440)'$ or in other words $1-(1-P)^{T\over 1440}$

Comment: It wont rain in T mins should be pow(1-P,T)? Shouldnt it? Meaning the product of probabilities of each minute?

Comment: Also can you please help with the complete point 1?

Comment: @Diffy Probability that it won't rain for the entire day of 1440 minutes. is (1-P). So, for T minutes, It has to be T/1440 .